# UITableViewCell selection problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I have created a class named `ListCell` which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. This is so that I can put more content in the view such as images, labels, etc. easily, instead of coding inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I have added a label to display an address in the cell. I have another class, inheriting from `NSObject`, to hold that address. The address is a string that comes from a web service. I am using  the following code to fetch the address from the class named `Itemsforcell`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)cellTableView 
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    ListCell *cell = (ListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = (ListCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:1];

    } 
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    Itemsforcell *items = [self.Itemsforcell objectAtIndex:row];

    cell.address.text = items.address;
    return cell;      

}
```

My problem is that sometimes my cell doesn't get selected with the first click on it, only after the second. This doesn't happen for all the cells. It happens randomly for any cell, and at times it doesn't occur. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please any body suggest me a solution to this weird problem. Thank you one and all.

Comment: Maybe, If you are displaying an image which is getting URL from web service, is taking time to load. Just check if this happens if you wait for few seconds and then click on it. If so, what is suggest you is to go for asynchronous images.

Comment: No Nitish i am not displaying the image.But i will use ur suggestion when i will have a situation to use an image from the web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you're holding up the main thread by downloading that string. *You should never carry out network activity on the main thread*. Spin it off to its own thread, and when it finishes, change the UI on the main thread.